# Auto increment is not working after 10 in Rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have wrote this code in my model to auto increment my notice_no column for every row creation in my model [image: model.rb]

but it increments from 1 to 10 numbers after that it is not increments instead of that it is printing as [image: increments automatically till 10]

[image: after 10 it is not increment instead of that printing number 10 only]

Comment: Why don't you just add auto increment to that column?

Comment: i added and tried that auto increment also but it is also giving same result @RailsOuter

Answer (score 1):

Your `notice_no` field is `varchar` (i.e. string) (not a `integer` type). Just change in to `integer` in your migration file and rebuild/migrate database.

```
mysql> show columns from test_num;
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| num   | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from test_num;
+------+
| num  |
+------+
| 8    |
| 9    |
| 10   |
+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select max(num) from test_num;
+----------+
| max(num) |
+----------+
| 9        |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: thank for your reply @maxd but i have given to_i to downcast string to integer there...